# Drupal 7 add fields to show in RSS feed for taxonomy

Tags: drupal-7, rss, drupal-taxonomy

iam having troubles with RSS feed. I have found that I can get feed for specific taxonomy just adding /feed after that taxonomy, but how is possible to add/remove fields from that, where can I found this "view" for this feed?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try to take a look into module who create this view ? maybe some hook are provided to override rendering or data pre rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is defined into hook_menu from `taxonomy.module` :

```
$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed'] = array(
    'title' => 'Taxonomy term',
    'title callback' => 'taxonomy_term_title',
    'title arguments' => array(2),
    'page callback' => 'taxonomy_term_feed',
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'taxonomy.pages.inc',
  );
```

it call function `taxonomy_term_feed`

```
function taxonomy_term_feed($term) {
  $channel['link'] = url('taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
  $channel['title'] = variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal') . ' - ' . $term->name;
  // Only display the description if we have a single term, to avoid clutter and confusion.
  // HTML will be removed from feed description.
  $channel['description'] = check_markup($term->description, $term->format, '', TRUE);
  $nids = taxonomy_select_nodes($term->tid, FALSE, variable_get('feed_default_items', 10));

  node_feed($nids, $channel);
}
```

it call function `node_feed` into `node.module` line 2575

So you can analyse those function to understand how it works and find solution

Comment: Is it possible to override it, or add something to it? Its system module, i cannot simply edit it, I guess

Comment: You can add a drupal_alter() function to alter data without change core/contrib module https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7.x